# RegEx: getting end of the line

Tags: regex, powershell

I am looking for a RegEx at the end of a line to match the last comment (if there is any)
without the final ;-separator after the last field of the line.
The line may be:

```
   $line = ";2014.03.22;some optional comment;"    # this
   $line = ";2014.03.22;"                          # or that
```

If  do this

```
   $found = $line -match ';(\.+?);(.*)'
```

the last ";" will be part of the match.
What do I have to do not to catch the final ";" ?

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Comment: Do all lines start with a semicolon, followed by a date and another semicolon? Can there be any other text except for the optional trailing comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this?

```
$line -match ';(.+?);([^;]*)'
```